# How to sync website Events with iPhone calendar using ics file?

Tags: iphone, icalendar

I have a database with e.g. birthdays of some people. Now I can use iCalcreator to easily write a php script to dynamically create an ICS file and print it to the browser. If I navigate to that address with my iPhone it catches the birthdays and I can add them to my iPhone calendar.

If I delete a birthday from my database, the script will create the same ICS file but of course without that deleted event. However, if I navigate with my iPhone to that new ICS file it does not synchronize the events, more specifically my iPhone does not delete the missing event out of its own calendar.

As I researched I should add the event also to that new ICS file but with method CANCEL (does the event only require method CANCEL and UID?).

Do I have to keep all my deleted events (or their UID) and publish them as cancelled in my ICS file forever?